# Use subselect results at WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I want to merge these two selects, but I'm not very well with SQL.
I want to use the resulting data of these two columns, (sAuftrag, sInfo1) of the first select, at the second select.

I have to work with a MS-Access DB, via a OLEDB-interface which knows SQL commands.

**first select:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT sAuftrag, sInfo1 FROM tblStückliste
```

results are (count=32):

```
BA15.00929 22
BA15.00929 6, .... ("BA15.00929" is sAuftrag, and "22" is sInfo1)
```

For each result of these 32, I make a second select with the received data in WHERE clause.

**second select:**

```
SELECT ID, (dwStückzahl*dwLänge) AS dwLaufmeter, dwDicke, dwBreite
FROM tblStückliste
WHERE sAuftrag = 'BA15.00929' AND sInfo1 = '22'
```

results are (count=1-4 per select):

```
209 34860 17 78
210 47250 17 78
211 110250 17 78
....up to four
```

I tried a lot of variations to find a solution, e.g.

```
SELECT ID, (dwStückzahl*dwLänge) AS dwLaufmeter, dwDicke, dwBreite, SS.sAuftrag, SS.sInfo1
FROM tblStückliste,
    (SELECT DISTINCT sAuftrag, sInfo1 FROM tblStückliste) SS
WHERE sAuftrag = SS.sAuftrag AND sInfo1 = SS.sInfo1
```

**EDIT: ##########################**

ok, my table has entries which belong together. These entries can be identified by the fields sAuftrag and sInfo1. So you can call it groups, there are groups of entries in my table. Next step is to calculate (dwStückzahl*dwLänge) AS dwLaufmeter and also get ID, dwDicke, dwBreite of each entry.

Additionally I want to add up the dwLaufmeter of all entries in a group.

The target should be to know the dwLaufmeter of each group, and all ID's of all entries of a group.

These two selects up there give my the correct data, but I want to do it in one SELECT statment.

Comment: It is not quite clear why `SELECT ID, (dwStückzahl*dwLänge) AS dwLaufmeter, dwDicke, dwBreite, sAuftrag, sInfo1 FROM tblStückliste` does not meet your requirements. Post expected output for some input.

Comment: also used GROUP BY function

Comment: Which RDBMS are you actually using? You have tagged mysql and sql-server, and you say Access in the question? Which one of those is it? Can't be all.

Comment: Radim Bača is right. It doesn't make sense to write a query "show me all tblStückliste entries that exist in tblStückliste", as this would merely be "show me all tblStückliste entries".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that this is your solution:

```
SELECT ID, (dwStückzahl*dwLänge) AS dwLaufmeter, dwDicke, dwBreite, SS.sAuftrag, SS.sInfo1
FROM tblStückliste,
    (SELECT DISTINCT sAuftrag, sInfo1 FROM tblStückliste) SS
WHERE sAuftrag = SS.sAuftrag AND sInfo1 = SS.sInfo1
```

**What that query does is create an INNER JOIN between tblStückliste and SS**

However, PLEASE note that the "best practice" is to use "explict join" syntax, and a better way to write the query is:

```
SELECT ID, (dwStückzahl*dwLänge) AS dwLaufmeter, dwDicke, dwBreite, SS.sAuftrag, SS.sInfo1
FROM tblStückliste
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT sAuftrag, sInfo1 FROM tblStückliste) SS
       ON sAuftrag = SS.sAuftrag AND sInfo1 = SS.sInfo1
```

Also, you should prefix every column reference by a table name or table alias

```
SELECT T.ID, (T.dwStückzahl*T.dwLänge) AS dwLaufmeter, T.dwDicke, T.dwBreite, SS.sAuftrag, SS.sInfo1
FROM tblStückliste T
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT sAuftrag, sInfo1 FROM tblStückliste) SS
       ON T.sAuftrag = SS.sAuftrag AND T.sInfo1 = SS.sInfo1
```